# How to retrieve data from one column refer to another two columns from the same table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a table name

> flight_info (flight_id, flight_no, depart_from, destination,
>   depart_time, arrive_time)

Now I want to retrieve only

> flight_id on the basis of column depart_from and destination

I wrote the SQL as following:

```
string str = "SELECT fligth_id FROM flight_info WHERE  depart_from = @depart AND destination = @destination"
```

While running, it's showing an error pointing `@depart` and `@destination`. 
Can you help me, How can I specify those scalar variable.?

I tried it..

```
SqlDataReader myReader;
string depart = myReader["depart_from"].ToString();
string destination = myReader["destination"].ToString();
```

But, it's not working. 
Help needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using parameters in your query, but you didn't specify them.

Try like this;

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   connection.Open();
   using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT fligth_id FROM flight_info WHERE  depart_from = @depart AND destination = @destination", connection))
   {
        command.Parameters.Add("@depart", depart);
        command.Parameters.Add("@destination", destination);
        SqlDataReader myReader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
           int fligth_id = reader.GetInt32(0);
        }
   }
}
```

Since your query returns only `fligth_id` column, you can't access `depart_from` and `destination` columns with that way. `SqlDataReader` reads database rows *one-by-one*.

If you return other columns in your query like;

```
SELECT fligth_id, depart_from, destination
```

You can read them the same way like;

```
while (myReader.Read())
{
    int fligth_id = reader.GetInt32(0);
    string depart_from = reader.GetString(1);
    string destination = reader.GetString(2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks .. It helped me. :) 
And I want to Pass this value into another pages.
 'Response.Redirect("Booking.aspx? @flight_id: " + flight_id + " &flight_no: " + flight_no+ " &flight_name: " + flight_name );'

In booking page 
           ' String str1 = Request.QueryString["flight_id"];
            String str2 = Request.QueryString["flight_name"];
            String str3 = Request.QueryString["flight_no"];'

But the page shows nothing